# Set environment variable for applications on startup

Tags: macos, high-sierra, launchd, environment-variables

How do you set an environment variable on startup so that it can be used in applications?

For example, `ATOM_HOME` is used by Atom.

Comment: What method do you use to start atom? Which version for the app and which build / version for macOS.

Comment: I start it from the application bundle, and use High Sierra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

The solution uses two files: `environment.plist` and `environment.conf`.

`environment.plist` should be placed in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` for a per user solution (recommended), or in `/Library/LaunchAgents` for a global solution (not recommended – potential security loophole).

`environment.conf` can be placed almost anywhere. `$PATH_TO_ENVIRONMENT_CONF` can be relative, but only to the 'default' environment variables, or any that are defined in a `EnvironmentVariables` key. <sup>[1](http://www.launchd.info/)</sup>

`environment.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>local.launchd.environment</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>sh</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>xargs -L 1 launchctl &lt; $PATH_TO_ENVIRONMENT_CONF</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

`environment.conf`:

```
setenv ATOM_HOME $HOME/.config/atom
setenv SOME_VAR "Use quotes if spaces are necessary"
```

## How it works

When a user logs in, the LaunchAgents in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` are executed. In this case, `sh -c xargs -L 1 launchctl < $PATH_TO_ENVIRONMENT_CONF` is executed. `launchctl` manages daemons and agents. In this case, we are using it to set an environment variable accessible to all applications and the shell.

```
xargs -L 1 launchctl &lt; $PATH_TO_ENVIRONMENT_CONF

xargs                     # xargs converts stdin to command line arguments
xargs -L 1                # Tells xargs to invoke launchctl for each line
           launchctl      # Run launchctl with the arguments
                     &lt; # Since a plist is an xml document, angle brackets must be escaped. 

                     &lt; $PATH_TO_ENVIRONMENT_CONF
                          # This tells xargs to read input from the file at $PATH_TO_ENVIRONMENT_CONF
```

This solution can also be extended to other launchctl subcommands.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in High Sierra.

Comment: Still works for me.